# Joining NonEmpty types in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

If I have two generic objects of type (NonEmpty a), how can I join those two objects into a new (NonEmpty a), just like `++` does with lists?

I was expecting to be able to do something like the following

```
let x = 1:|[]
let y = 2:|[]
x ++ y
```

However, this  gives me the following error

```
<interactive>:65:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: [a]
                  with actual type: NonEmpty a0
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: x ++ y
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = x ++ y
    • Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:65:1)

<interactive>:65:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: [a]
                  with actual type: NonEmpty a1
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘y’
      In the expression: x ++ y
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = x ++ y
    • Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:65:1)
```

What this tells me is the `++` operator isn't defined for NonEmpty types. Is a similar operator available to do the same thing?

Comment: NonEmpty has a Semigroup instance (they are the free semigroup) so you can append them using the Semigroup method: `x <> y`

Comment: I can hardly help myself but engage in a bit of fun pedantry... NonEmpty isn't really the free semigroup.  Depending on how you define freedom, it would either include only the *finite* non-empty lists, or a structure that can be infinite at both ends, like [1,3,5,7 ...  8,6,4,2].  `NonEmpty` is permitted to be infinite, but only on the right. @Iceland_jack

Comment: The specialized web search engine Hoogle could have found function [append](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=NonEmpty%20a%20-%3E%20NonEmpty%20a%20-%3E%20NonEmpty%20a) for you. Its [library definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:append) mentions it is just a specialization of <>.